# How do I connect libraries in eclipse c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, path, libraries

When I create new/c++ project/debug/advanced setting, what do I do next? In the include tab, I have include the path to the  libraries? why is "Launch failed. binary not found" and "
undefined reference to `WinMain@16' ex      line 0, external location:"

Comment: Modern IDEs corrupt newcomers' minds with terms like "add a library to a project". As for myself, I first got acquainted with the "compile unit", "compiling" and "linking" concepts, then I got the view how to build programs with external libraries.  In your case, you probably need to specify the link-time library location so it's linked with your program.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to add the proper library paths to your project. Right-click your project and select Properties. This will bring up the property editor. Under the C/C++ Build|Settings you use the Linker section to set up libraries. I have a screencast on unit testing but you cans skip most of the first two minutes, around 1:50 in I demonstrate the process of adding include paths, around 2:50 in I show adding library paths. So if you have a few minutes you can watch the following video.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LnAuAJfMRy8